# How can I make this form responsive for mobile?

Tags: html, css, popup

I am trying my popup form responsive but unsuccessfully.
Any help will be appreciated!

That's the landing page URL - yogavoga.com/2weekdiet

```
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rga(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85); 
      padding-top: 65px;

}


.modal-content {
  margin: 5px auto; 
  width: 95%; 
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #888;border-width:3px;

}
```

I'd like to make it responsive for mobile as well.
Tried but couldn't get the right result.

Comment: Show us what you tried then, and provide a proper [mre] of it.

Comment: What I've added as a code is what I've tried... probably something is missing but I don't what exactly.

Comment: That alone is not a proper [mre]. And no, we don’t want to have to determine the rest from the live site you referred to - because that might change after you solve this problem, and that would make the question incomplete for people with similar problems who come across it in the future. So, please add a proper [mre], and also describe what exactly you want to achieve - _“couldn't get the right result”_ tells us very little about what exactly you would consider the _right_ result to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use media queries to make your website responsive.

here is the list of media queries for different device sizes:

```
 /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Now you have to write device-specific css in one of the above media queries.
like :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .modal {
          //add Mobile specific css for responsive design.
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately still no. It seems like the screen is getting wider once I open up the form and I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: can you post full form and what you tried with a media query? There is a possibility that you have missed something cause this works in all cases.